# intellij terminal doesn't know git

Tags: github, intellij-idea

in in the same device, I can write git commands in the cmd, but as soon as I write "git" in intellij terminal I get these red lines:

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

what is the reason and what can I do?

I am trying to push my project directly from ij to github

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to open a terminal in IntelliJ to push.
Simply use "Push" action that can be found either on toolbar or under `Git` menu.

See more for Push here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#push

Comment: yes, I can use ij tools, but with a push button, how can I find where did my code pushed to?

Comment: When you press "push" you will be prompted with a dialog where you can see branch-name: your-remote-repository. For example `main:origin` 
so `origin` is your destination repository, where the code would end up. If you don't know the exact URL, you can go to Git | Manage remotes menu